# Angular Abstracts & Data Mutations

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-5, angular2-changedetection

I am stuck with a fairly weird bug? which relates to a component based on an abstract class (or so is my guess).

So there are multiple sibling components which are rendered based on an array length with an `*ngFor`. The siblings (based on an abstract class) get their data via `@Input` properties, then handle the data in their ways and display it. So far so good. `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` ftw, etc. However as soon as I hover over one of the components, the data mutates on-the-fly (I have no other explanation or correct term for it) and is being reset to the data of the last sibling within that template.

```
<Router-outlet>
  <ParentComponent>
    *ngFor
    <Sibling1>
      <ChildComponentA>
      <ChildComponentB>
    <Sibling2>
      <ChildComponentA>
      <ChildComponentB>
    <SiblingN>
      <ChildComponentA>
      <ChildComponentB>
```

I've breakpointed every possible line of the code - everything is set correctly. But as soon as I hover over the component, I believe the change detection kicks in and takes the data from the last sibling and overwrites every other sibling. Not deep, mind you! The children of the siblings are still correct and display everything as is. But the template of that hovered sibling component is corrupted. I am truly lost.
I've used `[...array]` and `array.slice()` and what not to make sure that the arrays are unique. Nothing has helped so far.

Here is a sample (the code is fairly complicated to just dump it here).

**parent.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="v === 'user'">
    <div *ngFor="let e of employees">

        <div>
            <h3>{{ e | name }}</h3>
        </div>
        
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="days; context: { e: e }"></ng-container>

    </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #days let-l="l" let-e="e">
    <div>
        <sibling
            [weeks]="weeks"
            [viewMode]="v"
            [loc]="l"
            [emp]="e"
            [realDates]="realDates"></sibling>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Here is the **sibling.component.html**

```
    <div *ngFor="let day of selectedWeek;">
        <div>
            <i *ngIf="viewMode == 'location'"
                class="ico"
                [ngClass]="{
                    'i-x-o': !day.isOpenOnDay && day.isSpecialDay,
                    'i-day-time': day.isOpenOnDay,
                    'is-special': day.isSpecialDay
                }"></i>
            <childA></childA>
        </div>

        <div>
            <childB [day]="day"></childB>
        </div>

    </div>
```

`<childB>` stays put and displays the data of `day` alright. But as as soon as I hover over `childA` or `childB` or even that `<i>` with icon classes - the `day` object from the last sibling is used. The `selectedWeek` in the sibling component is an array derived from `weeks` input, then manipulated, sliced and spread and what not.

- parentComponent: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
- sibling: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
- childA: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
- childB: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering: the solution was to convert the variable `selectedWeek` into function. After that everything goes as it was meant to. So in **sibling.component.html**:

```
<div *ngFor="let day of selectedWeek()">
    <div>
        <i *ngIf="viewMode == 'location'"
            class="ico"
            [ngClass]="{
                'i-x-o': !day.isOpenOnDay && day.isSpecialDay,
                'i-day-time': day.isOpenOnDay,
                'is-special': day.isSpecialDay
            }"></i>
        <childA></childA>
    </div>

    <div>
        <childB [day]="day"></childB>
    </div>

</div>
```

and then in the **sibling.component.ts**

```
public function selectedWeek(): Array<any> {
  // do stuff, return an array
}
```

I still haven't figured out the reason why a variable wouldn't work.